# Operator '+=' behaves weird

Tags: php, operators

My problem is that with this code I get 3, but as it looks to me I should get 1, but just don't have any idea how to fix it.

**Example Code:**

```
$counter = 0;
if (($counter = test2() !== false)) {
    $counter += 2;
    print $counter;
}

function test2() {
    return -1;
}
```

**Output: 3**

If I do it the other way around it works fine and I will get -1.
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**Example Code:**

```
$counter = 0;
if (($counter = test2() !== false)) {
    $counter -= 2;
    print $counter;
}

function test2() {
    return 1;
}
```

**Output: 1**

I hope that someone can explain this to me, because for me this is totally weird.

Comment: Performing an assignment in a conditional check is a famously bad idea, for exactly this reason.  (In terms of readable and followable code, `!== false` doesn't help either...)

Comment: Operator precedence: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php  `!==` binds tighter than `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php treats this like:

```
$counter = 0;
if ($counter = (test2() !== false)) { //see?
    //so counter is equal to 1
    $counter += 2;
    print $counter;
}

function test2() {
    return -1;
}
```

this way is better:

```
$counter = 0;
if (($counter = test2()) !== false) { //see?
    //now counter is -1
    $counter += 2;
    print $counter;
}

function test2() {
    return -1;
}
```